# How do MySQL-Workbench and mysqldump return dumps with vastly different file-sizes?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

I observed that the dump of my DB done "by hand" in the CLI is a lot bigger (>800MB)
than the one produced by the Workbench (v8.0) (<500MB) and I am trying to figure out
why that's the case.

The Workbench shows in parts what it does:

`Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\WOLF\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4hx8j0cs.cnf"  --host=localhost --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --user=root --protocol=tcp --skip-triggers "psynet"`

I guess the magic is in the defaults-file but unfortunately this seems to be temporary created and eliminated automatically.
[EDIT]: it doesn't...it only contains the temporary password.

My command looks like this:

`mysqldump -e -uroot -p --skip-triggers --default-character-set=utf8 psynet > 'C:\Users\WOLF\psynet_testdump.sql'`

I'd appreciate input on how I can crunch this down further as I might have to upload this repeatedly in the future.

Comment: Did you try --compact parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately no significant impact.

By now I am very sure that the workbench does more stuff under the hood that it doesnt show in the interface. I mean...the command it shows would pretty much just write to the CLI if executed like this. And the magic of compression doesn't lie within the shown parameters. So I guess there is more of a pipeline behind it.

Answer (score 0):

- Look in the first hundred lines of each.  Do you see significant differences?
- Are `INSERTs` 'batched'?  That is one row per Insert statement versus lots of rows.
- Next time you run the Workbench dump have an other `cmd` running so you can (hopefully) capture the cnf file.
- For compressing after the fact, use WinZip / 7zip / etc to shrink the output file by a factor of about 3.  (And reverse the action when you need to read the dump.)